# Facebook Catalog not load images from AWS Cloudfront

Tags: facebook, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem when I try to upload some images to the Facebook Shopping catalog using a data source which in this case is this API.
[Api origin data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXCBI.png)

The images are delivered by AWS Cloudfront CDN, but facebook cannot download them.
[Facebook response Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvcyy.png)

I have tried to configure the facebook agent as indicated in the documentation if you have any example or case it would help me a lot.

I have also tried to have facebook get the image from the S3 repository itself, where the images are stored, without success.